# how to save the id that the fire base created

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Iam using firebase with angular 
 When adding data to firbase -how to save the id that the fire base created -
For example

```
$firebaseAreay(refLine).$add({
Name: 'sara', 
Id: $id
});
```

How to save the id that the firebase will created in the place of $id

Answer (score 0):

AngularFire is great for binding data to AngularJS views. But if you're just looking to write data to the database, you can stick to using the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK. In there, you'd implement this as:

```
var newRef = refLine.push();
newRef.set({
    Name: 'sara', 
    Id: newRef.key
});
```

If you're listening for this data anywhere else in your app, it will be picked up automatically. AngularFire is built on top of the JavaScript SDK, so the two interoperate perfectly.

Note that I don't think it's a good practice to store the key of an object inside that object. Doing so is an anti-pattern and wanting to do this typically points to problems in your design.

I'd recommend not storing the key as a property and simply doing:

```
refLine.push({ Name: 'sara' });
```